# Remove images from draw.io/diagram.net org chart

Tags: app.diagrams.net

diagram.net (formerly, draw.io) has a very convenient org chart template, but when I remove the images from each node (box/person), the text does not take up the space where the image was, and I can't find where to tell the object to use the whole width of the box for the text fields.

I'd like not to have to create my own objects because the org chart ones seem to have nice built-in functionality, like they understand their parent, children, siblings (they can collapse their siblings, for instance), or is that easy to recreate?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following: select a shape > Click Property/Value on the right > Text overflow: width and change position under Text tab if needed.

If this doesn't help, feel free to send the file to support@diagrams.net so we could see all the details.

Comment: Perfect! Somehow, it didn't occur to me to expand the Property/Value section. Thank you.